# How to detect if a variable is set or non-existent?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to detect if a variable is set to true or not even set, but when this happens and it's not set, the batch file when executed will crash the system. How to fix this?

eg:

```
:Shell
if %SHELL%==true goto SkipShell
SETX SHELL TRUE
:SkipShell
```

Comment: See `if /?` particularly `if defined`. A technique most people use is `if "%SHELL%"=="true" goto SkipShell` so there will always be quotes on both sides of `==`.

Comment: Using `if "%SHELL%" == "" goto NotDefined` (i.e., using quotes) will check that  `SHELL` is defined and not empty. You can reverse the sense of the test with `if not ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been reading slowly `if /?` and realised there is a simple way of fixing this.

```
:Shell
if DEFINED SHELL goto SkipShell
SETX SHELL TRUE
:SkipShell
```

I'm doing this as I want to recognise in which PC was my file ran.
Thank you [Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6017774/noodles)!

Comment: No - this won't work as intended, unfortunately. If `shell` is empty, then the `if exist` will be executed as `if exist goto skipshell` so it will attempt to execute a program `skipshell` if `goto` exists. Please note that `setx` also assigns the value to the variablename only for **future** `cmd` instances - not for any existing instances **including the current instance**

Comment: `if exist` is intended to check whether a file or directory exists; to check whether an environment variable is defined, use `if defined`; for example: `if defined SHELL goto SkipShell` (do *not* enclose the variable name within `%%` here!)